# How did Batygin estimate when Planet Nine was ejected?

Tags: solar-system, 9th-planet, estimate

Konstantin Batygin has estimated that [if Planet Nine was ejected, it would have been ejected 3-10 million years after the formation of the Solar System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planet_Nine#Origin#Origin).

I'm curious as to how he arrived at this figure. Was it through simulations of the early Solar System, a prediction of the alignments of orbits at that time, or something completely different?

Comment: The page you reference appears to be infected with some annoying pop-up/virus. I am unable to locate any source for the statement you are questioning; it does not appear to have been made by Batygin.

Comment: @RobJeffries It's a stupid scraping site, I have replaced the link

Comment: @RobJeffries I'm so sorry; I thought I had inserted the Wikipedia link, but I must have encountered a  redirect somewhere. Thank you for pointing this out; I should have been more careful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Page 12 of [Batygin & Brown (2016)](http://arxiv.org/abs/1601.05438) says that a speculative formation scenario can be drawn from recent solar system formation simulations by Bromley & Kenyon and by Izidoro et al. These suggest that the core of a nascent ice giant may have been ejected very early in the solar system's history in order to explain the properties of the observed planets; the formation of Uranus and Neptune was probably accompanied by at least one other ice giant.

The source of the claim you mention is actually an article by [Eric Hand in Science Magazine](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2016/01/feature-astronomers-say-neptune-sized-planet-lurks-unseen-solar-system).  He points out that possibly, to explain why this planet was ejected yet still remains part of the solar system in a much wider orbit, then you need it to have been slowed down by residual gas in the protosolar disk. So I assume the 10 million year is an (uncertain) upper limit on the dispersal of the disk and I would guess the 3 million year lower limit is just how long it takes to form a 10 Earth mass ice giant core at the distance of Neptune.